# Data annotations not working in view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a few different models with properties that I've decorated with data annotations for validation.

```
public class BillingModel
{
    [Required,
    DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required,
    DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerModel
{
    [Required,
    DisplayName("Address")]
    public string Adress { get; set; }

    [Required,
    DisplayName("City")]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

When I put them in a view model like this:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public BillingModel Billing { get; set; }
    public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }
}
```

They render out like this:

```
<input id="Business_FirstName" name="Business.FirstName" type="text" value="" />

<input id="Business_LastName" name="Business.LastName" type="text" value="" />
```

My Razor looks like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Business.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Business.LastName)
```

I have many properties that need to live in their own classes as each class contains specific methods. Even if I put `[Required]` on each property in the View Model it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also need to put the following `<script />` elements in your view (preferably the _layout.cshtml View if you will be using client side validation across all views):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Modify the paths accordingly.  But that should get your validation up and running.

Also, use the [ValidationMessageFor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721271.aspx) in your view.  Like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Business.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Business.FirstName)

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Business.LastName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Business.LastName)
```

Comment: My issue was that these objects were Entity Framework objects that which I created meta data for, but placed the partial classes in the wrong namespace.

Answer (score 7):

Just for anyone else who comes across this, in addition to the other answer, you also need to have the following web.config settings enabled:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

This is what enables the data annotations to have an affect on the rendered html.

Comment: This answer is just as important as the answer that has been accepted, you need both the JS and these settings in your web-config for this to work correctly.

Comment: This worked for me and you saved my day. Thank you!

Comment: I loooooove you!!

Answer (score 3):

Once you put the required Data Annotation in your Field in the View Models, for example
[image: rendered source of class Persona]

And, if it doesn't work, just write this in the section script in your **View page that you are using the ViewModel** like this:
[redundant rendered `<script />` elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azdrC.png)
I hope that can help you!
**And don't forget to use the tag decorator below to the field**
**@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Model.Name)**

here is the scripts :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more case: You have not added the reference of
**System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** in your current project layer.

TRY THIS: Navigate → Project(Top Left Corner) → Add Reference → **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations**
Select the Checkbox and Wallah!:D

[image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNLzi.png)